# 503 error (Service Unavailable) in the jetty server

Tags: jetty

What is the solution of **503 error (Service Unavailable)** in a Jetty server.
I am using jetty with the eclipse IDE besides the GWT as front end tool.

At the same time my one module is running good, but when I try to run my second module which is error free, I get the error 503 service unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

You've got an error in

> war/web.xml

Probably you forgot delete the servlets.

(It works for me. - If don't work, set in Run Configuration -> Server and Run Configuration -> GWT "Automatically select an unused port")

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know much about jetty but while informing me about it (what it is and what it does) I found [this](http://www.opennms.org/wiki/Jetty#Jetty_startup_problems) in a wiki:

> If jetty fails to show the expected pages when you try to login, and gives a 404 or 503 error, this can be caused by an error in one of the configuration files, especially etc/snmp-graph.properties. The place to look is logs/daemon/output.log.